# Adjoint of differential equation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ds.dynamical-systems, semigroups-of-operators

Motivation: Consider the ODE

$$y'(t)=Ay(t)$$ then it is true that the flow satisfies $\Phi(t)y_0=e^{tA}y_0$ and the adjoint of the flow is a solution to the adjoint equation
$$y'(t)=A^*y(t).$$

I would like to understand whether something like this is true in a more general context:

Given the linear ODE in a Hilbert space $H$

$$y'(t)=Ay(t)+By(t)\kappa(t)$$ where $A$ is the generator of a $C_0$ semigroup and $B$ a bounded operator $B:H \rightarrow H$ is bounded and $\kappa \in C_c^{\infty}$ a scalar function.

The solution for some initial state $y_0$ can be expressed in terms of a flow

$y(t)=\Phi(t)y_0.$
Thus, $\Phi(t):H \rightarrow H$ and one can consider the adjoint operator
$\Phi(t)^*.$

It is very tempting to assume that the adjoint flow operator solves

$$y'(t)=A^*y(t)+B^*y(t) \kappa(t).$$

Is this true? The problem is that the solution can often only be expressed as a mild or weak solution.

The weak solution for example reads for $x \in D(A^*)$

$$\langle \Phi(t)y_0,x\rangle = \langle y_0,x \rangle + \int_0^t \langle \Phi(s)y_0, A^*x+\kappa(s) B^*x \rangle ds$$

and I do not see how to infer anything from this formualtion about $\Phi(t)^*.$

Comment: A terminological remark:  since the linear equation $$y'(t)=Ay(t)+\kappa(t)By(t)$$ is nonautonomous, one cannot speak of the flow generated by it.  The object generated by it should be termed *process* (or, better, *semiprocess*):  $\Phi(s;s)=\mathrm{Id}_H$ for any $s \in \mathbb{R}$, $\Phi(u,s)=\Phi(u,t)\circ\Phi(t,s)$ for any $s \le t \le u$.

Comment: @user539887 in your terminology what I call the flow is $\Phi(t,0).$

Comment: Do you know [Evolution Semigroups in Dynamical Systems and Differential Equations](https://bookstore.ams.org/surv-70) by Chicone and Latushkin?

Comment: In general, consider a non-autonomous system $y'=A(t)y$. If $\Phi(t)$ denotes the solution operator (i.e. $y(t)=\Phi(t)y(0)$, then $\Phi'(t)=A(t)\Phi(t)$, so $(\Phi^*)'(t)=\Phi^*(t)A^*(t)$. In the autonomous case, the operators $\Phi^*$ and $A^*$ commute, but you cannot expect this in a non-autonomous system.